# Is the new Thor actually the Goddess of Thunder? Is the old Thor still the God of Thunder?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir

From what I understand, Thor was the God of Thunder before he was given Mjolnir. Were the powers of controlling thunder and lightning transformed into Mjolnir, so that now he no longer has them (since he doesn't wield it any more)? Or were the powers duplicated when the Hammer was created, so that now both the old and new Thor can control Thunder and lightning?

In any case, in a more abstract level, the new Thor is a human. Is she really the Goddess of Thunder, or is that just a nickname, like Thor is just a name the old Thor decided to give her?

I don't think this is a duplicate to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83830/prior-to-the-spell-cast-on-mjolnir-did-thor-control-lightning-on-his-own), because the fact Thor could control thunder and lightning before he was given Mjolnir doesn't mean he still can after Mjolnir left him. It does say whoever holds the hammer "possesses the power of Thor", but this sentence is a bit ambiguous; I mean, if whoever holds it is called Thor then it's pretty much meaningless. Perhaps 'Thor' in this sentence refers to the original Thor, but that would mean Mjolnir only grants the powers Thor possesses anyway, and he definitely became weaker after loosing it.

Comment: Hmmm... The answer to the referenced question looks like a solid answer to this one. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think so, "because the fact Thor could control thunder and lightning before he was given Mjolnir doesn't mean he still can after Mjolnir left him". What do you think?

Comment: I was focusing on the line that stated he didn't require the hammer to control thunder and lightning or storms, and that his father controlled Thor's powers. I'm not vtcing. Just comparing the two posts. :)

Comment: Okay then:] In any case it doesn't seem Odin controls Thor's powers, and certainly not Mjolnir's, since he opposed them both in the last years and didn't take their powers. I'm also inclined to believe Thor no longer controls lightnings, because he didn't do so ever since he lost Mjolnir (as far as I can recall).

Comment: The [Marvel.com website](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/55786/mighty_thor_2015_1) references her thusly; "*When DR. JANE FOSTER lifts the mystic hammer Mjolnir, **she is transformed into the Goddess of Thunder**, THE MIGHTY THOR"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She refers to herself as such in Thor vol 4. #2:

> With that hammer in my hand, I was the Goddess of Thunder. So I guess now the question is... what am I without it?

The former Thor (now going by Odinson) has shown that he has been capable of summoning lightning without his hammer in the past:

[image]

So it maybe Odinson does not need to be in possession of his hammer to be able to use his powers. However, it may be that once he looses his worthiness, some of his powers are removed. At any rate, thor has stated in "The Unworthy Thor" that he has to use his goat in order to fly without his hammer.

It should also be noted that Odinson was in possession of an bizaro version on the hammer prior to Secret Wars that allowed the unworthy to weild it, however, he dropped it at one point during a battle and was unable to pick it up. He is currently after the hammer left over from the ultimate universe.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but, taking into consideration everything you said, it seems the answer is "no". He still controls lightning, and there doesn't seem to be an indication that she is a Goddess of Thunder in any way; she just has the powers of the hammer.